# Confusion over Linq/lambdas in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a collection of a DTO, Department, and would like to extract only one of the columns for all the Department-objects. I know that in C# you can do like this:

```
List<Department> departments = corporation.GetDepartments();
List<int> departmentIDs = departments.ConvertAll(dep => dep.ID);
```

Out from my understanding this is use of LINQ, with the argument to ConvertAll() being a lambda expression. (?)

When trying to achieve the same in VB, it seems that one must define a Converter-method:

```
Dim departmentIDs As List(Of Integer) = coll.ConvertAll(New Converter(Of Department, Integer)(AddressOf ConvertDepartmentToInt))

Public Shared Function ConvertDepartmentToInt(ByVal dep As Department) As Integer
    Return dep.ID
End Function
```

Why is it like this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use lambdas in Visual Basic .NET too. The syntax is like this:

```
departments.ConvertAll(Function(dep) dep.ID)
```

For lambdas that don't return a value (like those of type `Action<int>`), use `Sub` instead:

```
Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! This syntax seems to be less documented than the C# syntax. Maybe because of popularity towards C#..